# Why is SPList's LastItemModifiedDate not the same as the modified date shown in the list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, document-library, splist

I have a document library that I am accessing programmatically as an `SPList`. When I use the `LastItemModifiedDate` property of the list, the DateTime returned is **{1/7/2010 1:37:41 AM}** but when I browse to the document library (with my web browser) I can see the most recent modified date is **7/01/2010 12:37 PM** (this is the correct *local* time when I edited the file).

This looks to me like a timezone issue, but I'm not sure where `LastItemModifiedDate` is getting its settings from.

What do I need to change so that `LastItemModifiedDate` and the time appearing in my browser agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check Site Settings => Regional Settings => Time Zone. If you convert your Local time to GMT using the given offset, to they match?

If yes, then you can try getting the Time Zone for the Site using [SPWeb.RegionalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.regionalsettings.aspx).[TimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spregionalsettings.timezone.aspx) and then either use [LocalTimeToUTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sptimezone.localtimetoutc.aspx) or [UTCToLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sptimezone.utctolocaltime.aspx) to convert between the timezone of the site and UTC (Note that on SharePoint, you could give each Site it's own regional settings and TimeZone).

Edit: Just double checked, SPList.LastItemModifiedDate is always UTC. I'll leave a comment [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx).

Comment: I believe that every date is stored as UTC in SharePoint internally. This is also why they need to patch SharePoint when DST changes happen (as this one here: http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/09/19/important-hotfixes-for-upcoming-daylight-savings-time-dst-change.aspx)

Comment: So do I. As every site in SharePoint can have it's own Time Zone and as you can move content between sites, I highly doubt that SharePoint always recalculates the date, but rather store it in UTC and then internally uses UTCToLocalTime (or whatever that uses internally) to display the dates.